# How to automatically export data from S3 bucket to external service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I would like to ask you about export data from AWS to external service. I am using S3 (scalable storage in the cloud) to collect my data in json format.

In my bucket every 5 minutes there is a new file with json data and now I would like to create something like to webhook to export this new collected data to my external service. Example scenario:

1. My service send data to AWS S3 bucket
2. The data are stored in bucket
3. AWS inform and export my new json file with data to external service

It is possible? If no, it is possible to get data from bucket by for example external rest api?

Cheers!

Comment: To what "external service" would you like to send it? How can the external service receive data? Or is this just a general question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do that using a lambda function - see the doc [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)

> Amazon S3 can publish events (for example, when an object is created
>   in a bucket) to AWS Lambda and invoke your Lambda function by passing
>   the event data as a parameter. This integration enables you to write
>   Lambda functions that process Amazon S3 events. In Amazon S3, you add
>   bucket notification configuration that identifies the type of event
>   that you want Amazon S3 to publish and the Lambda function that you
>   want to invoke.

Actually amazon has an [example of streaming data from S3 to Elastic Search](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples) so you should be able to re-use that with your own service

you need to make sure your bucket is configured with the following permission

- Lambda permits S3 to push event notification to it
- S3 permits Lambda to fetch the created objects from a given bucket

The [lambda function](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples/blob/master/src/s3_lambda_es.js)

```
/*
 * Sample node.js code for AWS Lambda to get Apache log files from S3, parse
 * and add them to an Amazon Elasticsearch Service domain.
 *
 *
 * Copyright 2015- Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Amazon Software License (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * A copy of the License is located at http://aws.amazon.com/asl/
 * or in the "license" file accompanying this file.  This file is distributed
 * on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND,
 * express or implied.  See the License for the specific language governing
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

/* Imports */
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var LineStream = require('byline').LineStream;
var parse = require('clf-parser');  // Apache Common Log Format
var path = require('path');
var stream = require('stream');

/* Globals */
var esDomain = {
    endpoint: 'my-search-endpoint.amazonaws.com',
    region: 'my-region',
    index: 'logs',
    doctype: 'apache'
};
var endpoint =  new AWS.Endpoint(esDomain.endpoint);
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var totLogLines = 0;    // Total number of log lines in the file
var numDocsAdded = 0;   // Number of log lines added to ES so far

/*
 * The AWS credentials are picked up from the environment.
 * They belong to the IAM role assigned to the Lambda function.
 * Since the ES requests are signed using these credentials,
 * make sure to apply a policy that permits ES domain operations
 * to the role.
 */
var creds = new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS');

/*
 * Get the log file from the given S3 bucket and key.  Parse it and add
 * each log record to the ES domain.
 */
function s3LogsToES(bucket, key, context, lineStream, recordStream) {
    // Note: The Lambda function should be configured to filter for .log files
    // (as part of the Event Source "suffix" setting).

    var s3Stream = s3.getObject({Bucket: bucket, Key: key}).createReadStream();

    // Flow: S3 file stream -> Log Line stream -> Log Record stream -> ES
    s3Stream
      .pipe(lineStream)
      .pipe(recordStream)
      .on('data', function(parsedEntry) {
          postDocumentToES(parsedEntry, context);
      });

    s3Stream.on('error', function() {
        console.log(
            'Error getting object "' + key + '" from bucket "' + bucket + '".  ' +
            'Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.');
        context.fail();
    });
}

/*
 * Add the given document to the ES domain.
 * If all records are successfully added, indicate success to lambda
 * (using the "context" parameter).
 */
function postDocumentToES(doc, context) {
    var req = new AWS.HttpRequest(endpoint);

    req.method = 'POST';
    req.path = path.join('/', esDomain.index, esDomain.doctype);
    req.region = esDomain.region;
    req.body = doc;
    req.headers['presigned-expires'] = false;
    req.headers['Host'] = endpoint.host;

    // Sign the request (Sigv4)
    var signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(req, 'es');
    signer.addAuthorization(creds, new Date());

    // Post document to ES
    var send = new AWS.NodeHttpClient();
    send.handleRequest(req, null, function(httpResp) {
        var body = '';
        httpResp.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        httpResp.on('end', function (chunk) {
            numDocsAdded ++;
            if (numDocsAdded === totLogLines) {
                // Mark lambda success.  If not done so, it will be retried.
                console.log('All ' + numDocsAdded + ' log records added to ES.');
                context.succeed();
            }
        });
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        console.log(numDocsAdded + 'of ' + totLogLines + ' log records added to ES.');
        context.fail();
    });
}

/* Lambda "main": Execution starts here */
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('Received event: ', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    /* == Streams ==
    * To avoid loading an entire (typically large) log file into memory,
    * this is implemented as a pipeline of filters, streaming log data
    * from S3 to ES.
    * Flow: S3 file stream -> Log Line stream -> Log Record stream -> ES
    */
    var lineStream = new LineStream();
    // A stream of log records, from parsing each log line
    var recordStream = new stream.Transform({objectMode: true})
    recordStream._transform = function(line, encoding, done) {
        var logRecord = parse(line.toString());
        var serializedRecord = JSON.stringify(logRecord);
        this.push(serializedRecord);
        totLogLines ++;
        done();
    }

    event.Records.forEach(function(record) {
        var bucket = record.s3.bucket.name;
        var objKey = decodeURIComponent(record.s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        s3LogsToES(bucket, objKey, context, lineStream, recordStream);
    });
}
```

Comment: Note that this lambda function has a time limit and will only work for small payloads (small depends on consumer, network etc). I think the lambda has to execute in < 15 minutes.